# Different type of Keyword in Pytrends

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, google-trends

I am trying to read trends of a specific trend of a specific type on Google Trends with Pytrends, but can only read a "simple" keyword.

For example:
https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=BR&q=%2Fg%2F11c0vm752r
String in the URL: /g/11c0vm752r
If you type this same string in the search field in Trends, it returns the Type of search you`re trying to do. In my example, looking for search around Nissan Kicks (Type = Small SUV) and not necessarily "Nissan Kicks" keyword.

I am trying:

```
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
keywords = ["/g/11c0vm752r"]
pytrends.build_payload(keywords, timeframe="today 5-y", geo="BR")
df = pytrends.interest_over_time()
print(df.head())
```

But it returns very small data, as if it is actually searching for this weird string.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am using Spyder.

Comment: Have you tried %2Fg%2F11c0vm752r ?

Comment: @AlPo That returns an empty DataFrame

Comment: @Felix try cat=855 or cat=610 or cat=1057. For more codes see https://trends.google.com/trends/api/explore/pickers/category?hl=en-US&tz=240